# MVC5 EF6 CodeFirst approach relationship with Users

Tags: entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I'm working with MVC5 EF6 CodeFirst and i want to know (and understand) the best way with Entity relationships.

All users must register then logged In (Identity) This part is Ok and works fine.

Next I created X entity classes for the application and New Scaffolded Item ( MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework) for each one, this part is OK too.

**My First problem is :** 
When a connected user create (sample  A product ) i just want to attach ProductId and UserId with a Foreign Key.
Actually, i create UserId in product Class. On Cshtml Page (Viewbag) i get `User.Identity.GetUserId();`
It works but without ForeignKey, so relationnship isbad.

**Second problem :** 
when user create a Product i now want to show all products(for him) with usersId(relationship) 
Best way is a **where** condition in My controller ?

```
ProductController.cs 
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Product.ToList());
}
```

Thx for all

Comment: One question per post please. Also, show the code in the controller. It's hard to fix something when it's invisible.

Comment: yeah, I am pretty unsure of what you are actually asking and that makes it hard to help =/

What is the relationship between your user and Product?? Can a user be tied to multiple products?  Can a product be tied to multiple users?  Is this a one to many, one to one, or many to many relationship?